# How to know if page visits occurred in expected order?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's suppose I have a table containing user sessions, the pages they visited in that session, and the datetime of those page visits. Users should visit pages in the correct order - that is, they should not be able to get to page 2 without first going through page 3.

Here (user 1, session 1) is a "good" session because she visited all of the pages in the correct order.

```
user_id  session_id  page_id  event_dt
1        1           1        2017-07-04 17:54:40
1        1           2        2017-07-04 17:54:43
1        1           3        2017-07-04 17:54:44
```

But (user 2, session 2) is a "bad" session because somehow she managed to land on page 2 before page 1

```
user_id  session_id  page_id  event_dt
2        2           2        2017-07-04 17:54:47
2        2           1        2017-07-04 17:54:49
2        2           3        2017-07-04 17:54:50
```

How can I determine that (user 1, session 1) is a "good" session, while (user 2, session 2) is a "bad" path using a SQL query.

#### Addendum

I have added a new `event_dt` column as suggested by [Degan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91218/degan) in the comments below.

Additionally, I am looking for queries using MySQL though I would also like to see queries using SQL Server (or any other implementation containing window functions).

Comment: You are correct, you will need to add an event date or timestamp column to your table.  You can then order the rows for a particular user_id and session_id and check if they match the good path that you want.  Since the row number queries can vary by the implementation of SQL, please tag with SQL-Server or MySQL or whatever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the pages twice, once in page order and once in date order.  Then compare them:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@us = concat_ws(user_id, session_id), @rn + 1,
                        if(@us := concat_ws(user_id, session_id), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn_p
      from (select t.*,
                   (@rn := if(@us = concat_ws(user_id, session_id), @rn + 1,
                              if(@us := concat_ws(user_id, session_id), 1, 1)
                             )
                   ) as rn_e
            from t cross join
                 (select @us := '', @rn := 0) params
            order by user_id, session_id, event_dt
           ) t cross join
           (select @us := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by user_id, session_id, page_id
     ) t
where rn_e <> rn_p;
```